# Is the contradiction 1=0 a valid contradiction for a proof?

Tags: soft-question, formal-proofs

I am new to proper mathematical proofs and was attempting to prove:

A prime number cannot be a perfect number.

Here is my go:

suppose n is a prime number.

Therefore the only divisors of n, are n and 1 by the definition of a prime number.

Now suppose n is a perfect number as well.

By the definition of a perfect number we can say n = 1, as the only positive integer divisor of n that is less than n is 1.

But there are no positive integer divisors of 1 that are less than 1. So 1 = 0 by definition of a perfect number.

Since 1 ≠ 0 we have reached the contradiction, and therefor we can say that a number cannot have both properties of being prime and perfect.

Is this proof valid? If not why? And in general is something blatantly wrong like n = m a “good enough” proof by contradiction if we already new beforehand that n ≠ m

Comment: As soon as you reached conclusion that $n=1$ you obtained the contradiction. There was no need to continue. The general idea of such proofs is to arrive at a false statement.

Comment: What definition of "perfect number" are you using? Whatever it is, it should easily imply that $1$ is *not* a perfect number, without the sidestep that this would somehow lead to $0=1$.

Comment: In principle the answer is yes though. How do we show there is no $x$ that solves $x=x+1$? By assuming there is such number $x$ and subtracting it from both sides.